# Can I add a data feed to a chart in joomla / joomshaper

Tags: javascript, charts, joomla

It seems a website I'm working on is built with an extension by sp joomshaper, it doesn't allow PHP or javscript to be added.  Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, most editors in Joomla strip PHP code from articles on saving.

The easiest way to get around this is by using a third party extension such as the free or paid version of Regular Labs Sourcerer.

If Sourcerer or similar won't work with a particular extension sometimes it can help if you change the order of the plugins in the Plugin manager at Extensions -> Plugins.

Comment: Thanks Neil but I've seen a lot of posts saying people are having trouble using it with joomshaper

Comment: You might need to be more specific to get a better answer e.g. is the problem with a particular JoomShaper template, SP Page Builder, or another extension?